# Genko Page layout Microsoft Word 2010 and 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language, page-layout-view

One of teacher in my school wants Genko page layout which is basically page layout for japanese.

I check on internet i should be seeing something like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Tjxu3yH.png]

This is my add-in snapshot. I am missing microsoft word 原稿用紙アドイン under application add-in.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RVAkgMR.png]

FYI- I do not know the language but one of the teacher use this. So I am wondering if you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I am missing microsoft word 原稿用紙アドイン under application add-in.

You need to install an East Asian language pack. See below for instructions.

---

#### Genko Settings

> Genko settings, short for genkō yōshi, refers to the Japanese term for
>   paper lightly printed with square grid background to assist
>   positioning of writing East Asian characters. The feature is derived
>   from writing or manuscript paper which uses a grid or squares; such
>   sheets are often divided into 200 or 400 squares. Each space is used
>   for one character. This feature is available in Word.
>
> **Instructions for Word**
>
> 1. East Asian versions of Office will have this feature by default. If you don't have one of these versions, you must first install an East
>      Asian language pack.
> 2. Ensure one East Asian Language set as your default editing language, as explained in [My Language Preferences: Office Editing
>      Languages](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_global_experience/archive/2010/03/18/my-language-preferences-office-editing-languages.aspx).
>
>    NOTE: The language you select will determine the default
>      Genko settings; for example, Korean has slightly different settings
>      than Chinese and Japanese.
> 3. Go to the Page Layout tab of the Ribbon.
>
>    [image]
> 4. In the Genko chunk, click on the Genko Setting button.
> 5. You will be able to specify whether to use a line grid or line-and-character grid to control formatting and what measurements
>      are used for the grid so that you can enter characters by using
>      fixed-pitch spacing (as in Genko or Gaozhi formatting).
>
>    [image]

Source [East Asian Page Layout Features in Office 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_global_experience/archive/2010/04/15/east-asian-page-layout-in-office-2010.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Yes I already have East Asian language pack which i installed it. Still I cannot able to see this @DavidPostill

Comment: "Ensure one East Asian Language set as your default editing language" - did you also do this?

Comment: I don't know how to set default editing language @Davidpostill

Comment: @k31453 See the link in point 2. in my answer - as explained in [My Language Preferences: Office Editing Languages](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_global_experience/archive/2010/03/18/my-language-preferences-office-editing-languages.aspx)

Comment: Hi I did installed Japanese version. Restarted but still not working. It doesn't change language. @DavidPostill

Answer (score -1):

Helped my father with this. He has Microsoft word 2013.  He was using Korean but in the settings proofing was not "downloaded". That was the hint that something was not installed correctly.

Eventually I re-installed the East Asian language pack. Correct version (32 vs 64) and reinstalled it. GENKO finally showed up.